# How to generate list attached to the TextField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have textfield which contains some text. And I need to generate list attached to the textfield so that when user selected some text and I recieved an answer from backend with info about that specific text the list was generated under that word or at least somewhere nearby the textfield.

The perfect example of what I need would be the dialogflow.

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orpiq.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you can say what instruments I can use or provide simple example

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. Stack overflow is for "why doesn't my code work" questions. It is not for asking how to do something. Divesting a library is also outside the scope since there could be many valid answers